# Confusing notation for the Probability of Continuous Random Variables

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

I am reading Kevin Murphy's book **Machine Learning a Probabilistic Perspective**, and I came across some notation in chapter 2 that is a bit confusing. Here is a screenshot

[image]

Basically, for equation 2.20, the the **P** for probability becomes upper case, compared to the **p** in equation 2.19 (and everywhere before it). Is this a typo or am I missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally lower case $p$ are mass (density) functions and upper case $P$ are the probability of an event. In this case, it seems like they are confusing the two.

Comment: Agree with combo above. Ill add a general note that while i think that book is good, i find the notation it uses to be haphazardly chosen and obfuscating.

Comment: @MatthewDrury than you, I thought I was the only one and there was some problem with my understanding ...